# Unable to start Android Studio in Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, opensuse

A fresh installation of Android Studio in Opensuse isn't working.JDK is already installed.Here is the exceptions it throwed when opened in terminal.

```
        Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.14)
        at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:103)
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
        at com.intellij.util.containers.LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.<clinit>(LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.java:54)
        at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
        at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentList(ContainerUtil.java:2550)
        at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createLockFreeCopyOnWriteList(ContainerUtil.java:2425)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryValue.<init>(RegistryValue.java:36)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.get(Registry.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.is(Registry.java:55)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.blockATKWrapper(UIUtil.java:108)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:95)
        at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.14)
        ...2 more
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find 'theUnsafe' field in the class sun.misc.Unsafe
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.getUnsafe(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:44)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.<clinit>(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:38)
        at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
        ...14 more


        Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.UIManager
        at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(libgcj.so.14)
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.updateUI(libgcj.so.14)
        at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
        at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
        at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(libgcj.so.14)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:336)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:312)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:291)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I am using Open JDK 8 that comes along with opensuse leap.

Comment: what JDK do you use?

Comment: I use openjdk which is default in opensuse leap

Comment: check version of JDK. I highly recoomend to install Oracle 8 JDK for Linux: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_Java#Procedure_with_development_kit_included_.28JDK.29

Comment: did you do it? it works now? No problem?

Comment: I added it as answer. If you could, please mark it as answer....

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check version of JDK.

I highly recommend to install Oracle 8 JDK for Linux from:
https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_Java#Procedure_with_development_kit_included_.28JDK.29

It should work.